# Get image from server side folder and display image in Vue

Tags: node.js, image, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display image from public folder of my node api directory. I want to display image in front end vue file. I don't know how to give source of image.

**This is the directory. I want to display image** `nodelogin.png`

[image: This is the directory. I want to display image nodelogin.png]

I want to display these images.

```
    <img :src="myimage" alt="Logo" width="80" height="80" />
```

This is my template code.

```
     async created() {
             this.myimage = await this.getImage();
         },
     methods: {
             async getImage(){
                 return await 'http://localhost:4000/api/public/nodelogin.png';
             }
          }
```

But this code gives an error response.
`Cannot GET /api/public/nodelogin.png`
Actually I'm new to node and Vue So I'm not **sure** whether my logic is correct or not.

*Do I need to do something from my backend side?*

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Cannot GET /api/public/nodelogin.png

Comment: does `<img src="http://localhost:4000/api/public/nodelogin.png" alt="Logo" width="80" height="80" />` work?

Comment: No, not working. 
```Cannot GET /api/public/nodelogin.png```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question posting.

If you want see png, you should input url :

`http://localhost:4000/nodelogin.png`

Good luck for your business.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the url `'/nodelogin.png'`

Comment: also you dont need to the getImage() method